# Saving and restoring non-Parcelable UI state for a dumb widget

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, user-interface

I have a "dumb" custom Android widget (as in `View`, not a home screen widget) that I need to have retain some state during screen rotations.  This `PlayerWidget` is essentially a media player UI with some buttons (back, forward, play/pause) and a progress bar.  It exposes the important bits of UI via getters.

There are a few separate `Activities`, each of which has a specialised controller object — these use the getters to update whether the buttons should be enabled, or have a "play" or a "pause" icon, and updates the progress bar as it receives callbacks from a background `Service`.

For example, in one controller's "start playing" method, it does this:

```
mWidget.getMiddleButton().setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
```

There's an `Activity` where screen rotation is handled via [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) — this calls `setContentView()` (because the layout differs between portrait and landscape), and binds the *newly-created* `PlayerWidget` to the *still-existing* controller object.

That works fine: progress updates start to happen on the new widget instance and the buttons work as expected.

However, the buttons do not have the correct icons because the `PlayerWidget` — not having knowledge of its controller — does not know how it is being used and thus what it should be displaying.

I was wondering whether the best idea would be to write `getState` and `restoreState` methods that the parent `Activity` can call before and after the new `setContentView()`, however I have no way of parceling a `Drawable` from the `ImageButtons` — or is there?

Or I considered wrapping the `ImageButton` objects which the `PlayerWidget` getters return, so that I can save (and thus later restore) the `Drawable` resource ID that the controller sets.

Alternatively, when I bind a new `PlayerWidget` to the controller, the controller could have some sort of "set-widget-UI-state-based-on-current-controller-state" method?  That's potentially complex for various reasons, but feels like the "right" way of doing it.

Any input on this slightly rambling problem would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion, I ended up using the "set-widget-UI-state-based-on-current-controller-state" approach, which was simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of hack but you could store the resource IDs of the drawables in your widget.  So on your widget have some code like:

```
private int mMiddleButtonImage;

public void setMiddleButtonImage(int resourceId) {
    mMiddleButtonImage = resourceId;
    getMiddleButton().setImageResource(resourceId);
}
```

The `getState()` and `restoreState()` method could then use the integer resource IDs rather than the drawables themselves.

Comment: Yeah. Though consumers also need to call things like `setEnabled()` on the buttons, which was why I mentioned returning a wrapped version of `ImageButton`, rather than relying on users to call a specific method on the widget for setting the button image.  The wrapped `ImageButton` would have a method like yours to capture the values for save/restore.

Comment: @Christopher - You did suggest my answer in your question; sorry that I missed that first time I read it.  I think this method will be preferable as storing int IDs will be much quicker than parcelling or serializing a Drawable, which may not be possible.  commonsguy also mentioned in another post that Bitmaps are handled in some special way in the Android memory model so I think leaving them alone and just remembering the IDs will be best.